# Create typed query through the session factory in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I generally want to do something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> c = qb.createQuery(Person.class);
```

But through the session factory rather than the entity manager.

Something like:

```
final TypedQuery<MyType> query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createTypedQuery(MyType.class, "query");
```

It should be trivial, but for some reason I couldn't find info on how to do it (if it is at all possible, but I think it should be).

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a method on Hibernate Session. Why not use EntityManager? It is part of JPA and therefore a Java EE standard?

If you are using Spring (Not my personal choice) you can use HibernateTemplate which hides the cast from you and provides type safe methods.

The cast is always going to happen somewhere!

Comment: Agreed, but if the cast does not happen in my code its not my responsibility, thats the idea :) Yes I'm using spring and the HibernateTemplate is exactly what I need I think, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible, because Session doesn't have any method that returns instance of javax.persistence.TypedQuery. Having org.hibernate.Query to implement javax.persistence.TypedQuery would have been quite a surprise, because they are different beasts (kind of part of different API inside Hibernate). Just for being in safe side I also checked from source.

Comment: I'm not looking for something that returns a `TypedQuery` exactly. I need a way to create a query that does not require me to cast the result. And to do this without use of the entity manager.

Comment: Also, there is no method Session, that would return something like: Query<ResultType>.